# Websocket client does not connect Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, websocket

Websocket client does not connect unless Developer Console is opened. After this it runs smooth. For the first time, opening of console is required.

This is specific to Internet Explorer 11. 
It is stable in chrome.

Comment: This is probably because you have `console.log()` statements in your code.  IE does not like those if the console is not open.  You can add this: `if (typeof console !== "object") {var console = {}; console.log = function(){};}` to work around it, but really you should remove `console.log()` statements when not running under the debugger.

Comment: @jfriend00 Even after removing all console.log statements its not working.
On investing further what I noticed is, the onMessage function is never  called in IE (I guess IE is not accepting any messages).

Comment: Without seeing any of your code, all you can get here is wild guesses.  I provided one wild guess, but if that's not it, this question is unlikely to go anywhere without you putting the relevant code in your question.